# Lambda Expressions with the File System Watcher

Tags: c#, .net, lambda, delegates

I can't figure out for the life of me where the two arguments come from in the following code. I've compiled it in Visual Studio, and it works, but when you use the lambda expressions to add the anonymous methods to the delegates for the FileSystemWatcher, how do the methods ever receive those two arguments? Where do they come from? Does the FileSystemWatcher return an array with the two arguments when the .Changed or .OnChanged events occur? If so, I haven't been able to find documentation that explains that. Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MyDirectoryWatcher
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("***** The File Watcher App *****\n");

            // Establish the path to the directory to watch.
            FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
            try
            {
                watcher.Path = @"C:\MyFolder";
            }
            catch (ArgumentException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to continue...");
                Console.ReadLine();
                return;
            }
            // Set up the things to be on the lookout for.
            watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess
              | NotifyFilters.LastWrite
              | NotifyFilters.FileName
              | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;

            // Only watch text files.
            watcher.Filter = "*.txt";

            // Specify what is done when a file is changed, created, or deleted.
            watcher.Changed += (s, e) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("File: {0} {1}!", e.FullPath, e.ChangeType);
            };

            watcher.Created += (s, e) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("File: {0} {1}!", e.FullPath, e.ChangeType);
            };

            watcher.Deleted += (s, e) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("File: {0} {1}!", e.FullPath, e.ChangeType);
            };

            watcher.Renamed += (s, e) =>
            {
                // Specify what is done when a file is renamed.
                Console.WriteLine("File: {0} renamed to {1}", e.OldFullPath, e.FullPath);
            };

            // Begin watching the directory.
            watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

            // Wait for the user to quit the program.
            Console.WriteLine(@"Press 'q' to quit app.");
            while (Console.Read() != 'q') ;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would run it in a different thread so it doesn’t get blocked.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean. Could you elaborate please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to pick one of the events...

```
watcher.Changed += OnChanged;
private void OnChanged(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e){
  // Handle event
}
```

You're actually adding a delegate to the Changed event's invocation list every time you do +=.  In this case, the delegate defines a signature that requires two parameters of type object and FileSystemEventArgs.

You can shorthand this using lambdas:
watcher.Changed += (sender, args) => {};

You need to look at the documentation for the event to work out the signature (or use an IDE like Visual Studio):
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher.changed

When the File System Watcher needs to invoke the event (to inform consumers something has happened), it will call all of the delegates in the events invocation list, passing the sender and FileSystemEventArgs.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I tried hovering over stuff in Visual Studio to look at the signatures and see what was going on. I could see that watcher.Changed was actually FileSystemWatcher.Changed, but the documentation is a little confusing. Now I can see it is a System.IO.FileSystemEventHandler, which bares the (object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e) signature.

Comment: No problem, glad I have helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if I'm not understanding the question. So the watcher.Changed is using a delegate. So you are passing in a block of code to execute when they get a certain action on there point. You are just passing them in code to run.

Here is a little more simple example.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DisplayString();
        Console.ReadLine();       
    }

    public static void DisplayString()
    {
        RunAction( (textToDisplay) =>
        {
            Console.Write(textToDisplay);
        });
    }
    private static void RunAction(Action<string> action)
    {
        action("This Is A Test");
    }
```

So in the `Action<string>;`  it is saying my delegate is expecting a string.  Which is passed in here

`action("This Is A Test");`

So In your example there code is

> public delegate void FileSystemEventHandler(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e);

Which means there code is passing you those two objects which you use through the (s, e)

So the watcher.Changed is declared

> Blockquote

public event FileSystemEventHandler Changed;

Comment: Thank you. Is the FileSystemEventHandler implicit? I don't see it in the code, but in the other version of this project using delegates it's there.